# Rails: What do model associations tangibly do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

I have the following models setup:

clinics

```
has_many :occupations, through: :clinic_occupations
has_many :clinic_occupations
```

occupations

```
has_many :clinic_occupations
```

clinic_occupations

```
belongs_to :occupations
belongs_to :clinics
```

I think the `has_many :clinic_occupations` in `clinics` is probably unnecessary, but it's what we have right now so I wanted to include it.  I am trying to only call occupations that have been associated with a clinic, or occupations that have no clinic id at all.  What is the correct way to do this, and what are these model associations tangibly doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the `has_many :clinic_occupations` in `clinics` is probably unnecessary

Nope, it is. In order for any `has_many _, through: _` to work, you need to supply **another association**. That's exactly what `through` stands for, "an association **through** an association". Under the hood, this uses `JOIN`-clauses for "lower" asssociated objects with "higher" ones . Since Rails 3 these can even be nested, producing a `JOIN`-clause through multiple tables at once.

What it does is create a bunch of methods for your model ([reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many)) with some caching underneath.

Why should you define that association explicitly? Because:

1. It's safer. Association name may not follow Rails convention and thus no assumptions can be made just with its name. Let's face it, sometimes this happens. More on that below.
2. It offers all the features `has_many` associations have in general. Association may contain details that do not violate conventions (like conditions).
3. It's more flexible. This way you can define multiple associations that point to the same class. It's **impossible** to follow conventions in this case, since **one name can only point to one method**.
4. It's clearer when looking at the model why a **single** method call queries **multiple** tables at once.

In fact, you **may want** to access the join model (`ClinicOccupation`) directly when speeding up certain queries. There are cases when you already know the needed object's `id` and want to use it in a query without fetching the entire object first with an extra query.